Loading in public ArcGIS online into R Studio using arcgisbinding
I'm trying to load in a large, publicly available imagery raster (found at https://gis.cookcountyil.gov/imagery/services/CookOrtho2024/ImageServer) into R using a combination of the arcgisbinding and sf packages.
This question Accessing ArcGIS Online feature dataset from R using R-ArcGIS Bridge got me 95% of the way there. However, I am unable to find the feature ID that I need to put in place of "**ID" to get the layer to load in properly.
arc.data2sf(arc.select(arc.open(
  "https://gis.cookcountyil.gov/imagery/services/CookOrtho2024/ImageServer/**ID")))


After a few days of troubleshooting, I realized the code should be
arc.data2sf(arc.select(arc.open(
  "https://gis.cookcountyil.gov/imagery/rest/services/CookOrtho2024/ImageServer/0")))

However, it appears that while the data is publicly accessible, there are some permissions that are still off limits, so it won't let me do this. Oh well!

https://gis.cookcountyil.gov/imagery/rest/services/CookOrtho2024/ImageServer/info/iteminfo I would use bounding box like https://gis.cookcountyil.gov/imagery/rest/services/CookOrtho2024/ImageServer/exportImage?f=image&bbox=1060672.7039393554%2C1824767.8955512524%2C1187350.3804661962%2C1906883.0692682562&bboxSR=102671&imageSR=102671&size=506%2C328&format=jpgpng&mosaicRule=%7B%22ascending%22%3Atrue%2C%22mosaicMethod%22%3A%22esriMosaicNorthwest%22%2C%22mosaicOperation%22%3A%22MT_FIRST%22%7D

For my purposes I need to load in the whole map
